# Text position off with Pillow Draw

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

Please help. Watermark text position drew with ImageDraw. Draw text is little bit different(approx 20-30 x and y) from canvas text position after I saved the image. I've provided the code below.

main.py

```
from window import Window

window = Window()
window.config(padx=50, pady=50)

window.mainloop()
```

window.py

```
from tkinter import Tk, Button, Label, Entry, Menu, END, ttk
from watermark_texts import WatermarkTexts
from watermark import Watermark


class Window(Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.title("Watermark")
        self.config(bg="#272640")
        self.attributes("-alpha", 0.99)

        self.watermark = Watermark(self)
        self.add_img_btn = None
        self.create_add_img_btn(self.watermark.ask_image_file)
        self.menu_bar = None

    def create_add_img_btn(self, command):
        self.add_img_btn = Button(text="Add Image", command=lambda: command(self.add_img_btn))
        self.add_img_btn.pack()

    def create_menubar(self):
        self.menu_bar = Menu(self)
        self.config(menu=self.menu_bar)

        file_menu = Menu(self.menu_bar, tearoff=0)
        self.menu_bar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=file_menu, background="#272640", foreground="white")
        file_menu.add_command(label="Save",
                              command=self.watermark.save_photo,
                              background="#272640",
                              foreground="white")
        file_menu.add_separator(background="#272640")
        file_menu.add_command(label="Exit", command=self.destroy, background="#272640", foreground="white")

        add_menu = Menu(self.menu_bar, tearoff=0)
        self.menu_bar.add_cascade(label="Add", menu=add_menu, background="#272640", foreground="white")
        add_menu.add_command(label="Add Watermark",
                             command=self.watermark.create_new_text,
                             background="#272640",
                             foreground="white")
```

watermark.py

```
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfile
from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw, ImageTk
from tkinter import Canvas, CENTER, END, dnd, Entry
from tkinter.filedialog import asksaveasfile
from watermark_texts import WatermarkTexts
import os


FILE_TYPES = [("Image files", ".png .jpeg .jpg")]


class Watermark:
    def __init__(self, window):
        self.image_file = None
        self.img_resized = False
        self.window = window
        self.canvas = None
        self.canvas_img = None
        self.water_mark_texts = []
        self.img_format = None

    def ask_image_file(self, btn):
        image_file = askopenfile(mode="r", filetypes=FILE_TYPES)

        self.img_format = os.path.splitext(image_file.name)

        if image_file:
            with Image.open(image_file.name).convert("RGBA") as img:
                self.image_file = img.copy()
                btn.destroy()
                self.load_image(img)

    def load_image(self, img):
        screen_width = self.window.winfo_screenwidth()
        screen_height = self.window.winfo_screenheight()

        # resize image if image sizes are larger than screen size
        if img.size[0] >= screen_width or img.size[1] >= screen_height:
            img = img.resize((screen_width - 100, screen_height - 100), Image.Resampling.LANCZOS)
            self.img_resized = True
        img_width, img_height = img.size

        img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
        self.canvas = Canvas(self.window, width=img_width, height=img_height, bg="yellow", highlightthickness=0)
        self.canvas.place(relx=.5, rely=.5, anchor=CENTER)
        self.canvas.create_image(self.canvas.winfo_width() // 2, self.canvas.winfo_height() // 2, image=img)
        self.canvas_img = img
        self.window.state("zoomed")
        self.window.create_menubar()

    def create_new_text(self):
        text = WatermarkTexts(self.canvas, self.canvas_img)
        self.water_mark_texts.append(text)

    def draw_watermark(self):

        canvas_width = self.canvas.winfo_width()
        canvas_height = self.canvas.winfo_height()

        # Create a blank image with RGBA mode
        txt = Image.new("RGBA", (canvas_width, canvas_height))
        img = ImageTk.getimage(self.canvas_img)
        # Create a draw object for the blank image
        draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
        for text_item in self.water_mark_texts:
            font_size = int(18 * canvas_width / self.image_file.size[0])
            font = ImageFont.truetype("arial.ttf", 18)
            x, y = text_item.x, text_item.y

            if self.img_resized:
                # Adjust the position of the watermark to match the Canvas size

                x = x * self.image_file.width // canvas_width
                y = y * self.image_file.height // canvas_height

            text = text_item.get_text_value()
            draw.text((0, 0), text=text, font=font, encoding="utf-8-sig")

        # img = ImageTk.getimage(self.canvas_img)
        # img = img.resize(self.image_file.size, Image.Resampling.LANCZOS)
        # output = Image.alpha_composite(self.image_file, txt)
        img.show()
        return False

    def save_photo(self):
        output = self.draw_watermark()
        return False
        save_dir = asksaveasfile(filetypes=FILE_TYPES,
                                 defaultextension=self.img_format)
        output.save(save_dir.name)
        output.show()
```

watermark_texts.py

```
from tkinter import Entry, StringVar, Text, CENTER


last_x = None
last_y = None


class WatermarkTexts:
    def __init__(self, canvas, canvas_img, *args, **kwargs):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.text_item = self.canvas.create_text(canvas_img.width() // 2,
                                                 canvas_img.height() // 2,
                                                 text="",
                                                 fill="white",
                                                 font=("arial", 14))
        self.create_entry()

        self.is_text_editing = False
        self.edit_entry = None
        self.x = canvas_img.width() // 2
        self.y = canvas_img.height() // 2

        self.canvas.tag_bind(self.text_item, "<Double-Button-1>", self.start_edit)
        self.canvas.tag_bind(self.text_item, "<Button-1>", self.on_text_click)
        self.canvas.tag_bind(self.text_item, "<B1-Motion>", self.on_text_drag)

    def on_text_click(self, event):
        global last_x, last_y
        last_x = event.x
        last_y = event.y

    def on_text_drag(self, event):
        global last_x, last_y
        x, y = event.x, event.y
        self.canvas.move(self.text_item, x - last_x, y - last_y)
        last_x, last_y = x, y
        self.x, self.y = x, y

    def start_edit(self, event):

        if self.is_text_editing:
            return

        self.is_text_editing = True

        item = event.widget.find_closest(event.x, event.y)
        if item:
            item = item[0]
            x, y = self.canvas.coords(item)
            text = self.canvas.itemcget(item, "text")

            text_var = StringVar()
            text_var.set(text)

            self.edit_entry = Entry(self.canvas, width=10)
            self.edit_entry.insert(0, text)
            self.edit_entry.place(x=x, y=y, anchor="w")
            self.edit_entry.focus_set()
            self.edit_entry.bind("<Return>", self.end_edit)

    def end_edit(self, event):
        new_text = event.widget.get()
        self.canvas.itemconfig(self.text_item, text=new_text)
        event.widget.destroy()
        self.is_text_editing = False

    def create_entry(self):
        screen_width = self.canvas.winfo_screenwidth()
        screen_height = self.canvas.winfo_screenheight()

        item = self.canvas.find_closest(screen_width // 2, screen_height // 2)

        if item:
            entry = Entry(self.canvas)
            entry.place(rely=0.5, relx=0.5, anchor=CENTER)
            entry.bind("<Return>", self.end_edit)

    def get_text_value(self):
        return self.canvas.itemcget(self.text_item, "text")
```

P.S. My code is a bit messy right now. I can't care to refactor the code since find the solution.

Comment: After you pressed text. Did you move text to any position?

Comment: On line 25, I changed this `self.canvas.create_image(self.canvas.winfo_width() // 2, self.canvas.winfo_height() // 2, image=img)` to  `self.canvas.create_image(img_width//2, img_height//2, image=img)`. But it doesn't save text.

Comment: @toyotaSupra Text is moved after I pressed and moved it around. I've already tried with the code you've changed. It doesn't work either.

Comment: It worked for me..Btw, I'm using  Python 3.12.0rc3